# Best practice: capturing data from URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm looking for some advice on best practice in an MVC application. I can think of several ways of achieving what I want to achieve but I don't know what is considered best.

I am writing a discussion forum app and need to capture data from a URL to include in a post back from the page. I have links like this:

```
http://somedomain/Discussion/AddMessage/messageid/messagetitle
```

I need to include messageid and messagetitle in the form that is posted back on this page. What's the best way of going about this?

Ta! Mark

Comment: Do you have a route for this url?

Answer (score 0):

Your current url is more RPC, I would recommend reading about REST. I think a url like

```
http://somedomain/discussion/message
```

MessageId and MessageTitle are simply POST values.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/233572/Build-truly-RESTful-API-and-website-using-same-ASP

Comment: Can you recommend some reading for REST in MVC? None of the MVC books I have cover REST.